# Tile background - black spaces between tiles

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, background

I wanted to experiment with image background of my WPF app. I downloaded a few textures, but unfortunately I have a problem.
Here's my XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="458" Width="473">
    <Window.Background>

        <VisualBrush TileMode="Tile" Viewport="0,0,0.5,0.5" Stretch="None">
            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                <Image Source="Images/binding_dark.png" Stretch="None">
                    <Image.OpacityMask>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/binding_dark.png" Stretch="None" TileMode="Tile"/>
                    </Image.OpacityMask>
                </Image>
            </VisualBrush.Visual>
        </VisualBrush>
    </Window.Background>
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

It's just an empty window, but that's just to see better what the issue is.
Here's the result:
[image: Weird spacings]

I wanted to get a nice texture as a background of my app, but for some reason the images do not align with each other - there is this strange black spacing between them. What's the reason for this?

//EDIT
Just to clarify:
I'd like to have a background built of many of tiled copies of the same image - not one imgage filling the whole window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get tiled background without space between you need to add: `Stretch="Uniform"`

Also you should set Viewportunits to Absolute and size. Change 32 to size of your Image in code below:

```
ViewportUnits="Absolute" Viewport="0,0,32,32"
```

Full code:

```
<Window.Background>

<ImageBrush ImageSource="/TestApp;component/Images/bg.png" ViewportUnits="Absolute" Viewport="0,0,32,32" Stretch="Uniform" TileMode="Tile" />   

</Window.Background>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the background of the grid, not the window, like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Backgroud>
        <ImageBrush Source="Images/binding_dark.png" x:Name="image" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
    </Grid.Background>
</Grid>
```

You can set the background of the whole window but i'm not sure that this is a good practice

Comment: I tried your code, but it's not the result I want to get. My image is of rather low resolution. I'd like to have a kind of grid of these images displayed one next to each other. I don't want one image to fill the whole window - this way it looks pixelated.

Comment: i also tried to set TileMode fo the image to "Tile", but it doesn't change anything

Comment: @Loreno, hmm, interesting, check your image. doesn't it have a transparent border? i bet it is a png